# VBA To Search Specific Column in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to search a specific column in Excel (Column K) using the below VBA code but when I run the macro it instead searches the whole sheet instead of the specified column.

The problem is it firstly finds 'mycell1' in an earlier column, i.e. in Column C  instead of Column K which I don't want it to do.

I have also tried using 'xlByRows' in the 'Searchorder' which had the same issue.

Would greatly appreciate any help please

Thanks

```
Range("K:K").Select
Set foundcell1a = Selection.Cells.Find(What:=mycell1, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt _
    :=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False)
Set foundcell1a = Cells.FindNext
If Not foundcell1a Is Nothing Then
foundcell1a.Activate
End If
```

Comment: why don't you try `Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("K:K")` then `rng.Cells.Find(...`; using Select can cause problems if the user selects something else.

Comment: I would have expected the first find (i.e. the `Find`) would have found the entry in column K, and it would only be the **second** find (i.e. the `FindNext`) which would have looked in column C (due to it being `Cells.FindNext` rather than `Selection.FindNext`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `.Select` if you can possibly avoid it and most of the time, you can.

Try using `With...End With` constructs instead.  Be as specific as you can with the object you want to operate on.

```
Sub SearchK()
Dim mycell1
Dim foundcell1a As Range

    mycell1 = 1
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K:K")
        Set foundcell1a = .Find(mycell1, .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1))
        Set foundcell1a = .FindNext(foundcell1a)
        If Not foundcell1a Is Nothing Then
            foundcell1a.Activate
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Without a `With...End With`, you would have to repeat all the object identifiers so:

```
 Set foundcell1a = .Find(mycell1, .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1))
```

Would have to be expressed as:

```
Set foundcell1a = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K:K").Find(mycell1, .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1))
```

When VBA is evaluating a command it needs to evaluate each property preceding a period (.) every time it encounters it.  Using  `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K:K")` gets rid of 4 periods so it runs faster too.

The `Set foundcell1a = .Find(mycell1, .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1))` is saying find `mycell1` after the last used cell in column K so it loops back to find the first instance in column K regardless of the active cell.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
With Range("K:K")
    Set LastCell = .Cells(.Cells.Count)
End With

Set FoundCell1a = Range("K:K").Find(mycell1, LastCell)
If Not FoundCell1a Is Nothing Then
    FirstAddr = FoundCell1a.Address
    Range(FirstAddr).Activate
End If
```

Hope this helps!